# SQL EXISTS and IN operator nature of work?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, exists

I'm searching and trying to get the SQL `Exists` operator but couldn't understand it until i did it myself in SQL Server 2008 but still not clear on it, Help

e.g.

See I did some queries myself to check what it actually do,

```
// using IN
select 
    customers.cus_id, customers.cusName 
from 
    customers 
where 
    customers.cus_id IN (Select cus_id from products 
                         where prodCategory= 'Consumer electronics')

// using Exists
Select 
    customers.cus_id, customers.cusName 
from 
    customers
where 
    exists (select cus_id from products 
            where prodCategory = 'Consumer electronics' AND customers.cus_id = products.cus_id)
```

Both give the same result but when I remove this part from 2nd query's subquery

```
......AND customers.cus_id=products.cus_id
```

then it doesn't give correct results, returns all records form `Customers` table. Why? I think it will clear my concepts but little help is needed , HELP !

Comment: No sir, i just created it, take some rest :D

Answer (score 3):

Because it is the only connection between both tables. The `IN` approach links both tables via `cus_id` columns but the `EXISTS` connects   `customers` and `products` via PK and FK. If you remove it there is no relation anymore.

It's a matter of taste what you use. Meanwhile i prefer `EXISTS` / `NOT EXISTS` because it's readable and has no side effects because there is no connection  and nothing is selected at all.

Especially the `NOT IN` has an issue if the column is nullable. Worth reading: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/12/t-sql-queries/left-anti-semi-join

Answer (score 0):

If you remove that condition, you remove the connection betweeen the current record being evaluated in the where and the corresponding record in the subquery.

The subquery will have the same result for all records, and it will always have all products in the category. Thus, it will return all customers if there are any products in that category, regardless of any relation between the customers and the products.

When you are using `in`, you don't need that relation in the subquery, because the `in` operation is taking care of that relation.

Comment: ok but one thing that i don't get is that:
since subquery returns only TRUE/FALSE then how where' clause in case of EXISTS get 'cus_id' that is being selected in subquery ? it should be only possible for IN because taht returns some data, makes sense but how EXISTS ?

Comment: @SharmanJoshi: You can think of `in` runnning the subquery once, then picking out the records with the matching id, and `exists` running the subquery once for each record, to test if that specific record should be included in the result. (Naturally it doesn't actually run the subquery for each record, that would be terribly slow, but it works as if it would have done that.)

Answer (score 0):

This query:

```
Select cus_id from products where prodCategory= 'Consumer   electronics'
```

Will return a list of all `cus_id` values that have a `prodCategory` matching *Consumer electronics*.  The `IN` clause means that if `customers.cus_id` is contained in that list, the row will be returned.  So, it has somewhat of a built in AND.

However, the `EXISTS` clause means the row will be returned if the sub query contains any rows at all.  It doesn't care what the values of that sub query are.  Thus, you'd have to add the `AND` to prevent it from returning other rows that don't match `customers.cus_id`

Comment: ok grea but one thing that i don't get is that: since subquery returns only TRUE/FALSE then how where' clause in case of EXISTS get 'cus_id' that is being selected in subquery ? it should be only possible for IN because taht returns some data, makes sense but how EXISTS ?

Comment: @SharmanJoshi - That's why you need the `AND` clause.  It will return zero rows if there's no rows that have a prodCategory of 'Consumer electronics' and a cus_id equal to the parent row's cus_id.

Comment: OK Great
Just correct me if i'm wrong:

 SUBQUERY: Searches for email address, an address which is present in both tables, if it finds one then OUTER QUERY will display record for that email which is matched in subqry.

 .

 . 

 .

then now again SUBQUERY searches for another email add, if it finds a matching one then OUTER will again display record for that person.
So it mean that there is something hidden going on inside EXISTS which is quite apparent in IN but EXISTS take care of many things by itself.
RIGHT ? am i right ?

Comment: Think of the `IN` operator as a bunch of OR operators.  You can say `WHERE X IN (4,5,6)` instead of `X = 4 OR X = 5 OR X = 6`.  However, rather than `4,5,6` you can also have a sub-query.  The `EXISTS` operator says "if this subquery returns *any* results, then the expression is true."

Comment: ok but which is good ?

Comment: They're both fine.  Either can be slower or faster depending on the query, so learn to use `EXPLAIN` to see which is faster for your query.

Comment: EXPLAIN ? what's that ?

Comment: Check out [this article](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/)

Answer (score 0):

We can use both operators to fetch the same results. Let me take few examples before we go to the actuals.

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 returns records as shown below

Field1
1
2
3
4

SELECT * FROM TABLE_2 returns

Field2  Field3
1            4
2            6
3            7 
4            8
```

if we want to get the data in TABLE_1 which are present in “Field3″ of TABLE_2 then we can use the query with IN operator as

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE FIELD1 IN ( SELECT FIELD3 FROM TABLE_2)
```

We can also use the query with EXISTS as

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE EXISTS(    SELECT ‘X’
FROM TABLE_2
WHERE TABLE_1.FIELD1 = TABLE_2.FIELD3
)
```

when using EXISTS always use the where clause in the subquery to join the tables. Not doing so will result in fetching all the records from the main table. for eample if we consider the query below

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
WHERE EXISTS(    SELECT Field3
FROM TABLE_2

)
```

will fetch all the records from TABLE_1 and is same as the query

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1
```

The other difference is in performance( depending on which table is selected in outer/ inner query). EXISTS works faster than IN. you can check the performance plans of the above query for more info.